# How to programmatically cause RadAjaxManager to update a control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hi I have been having this issue in many development requests. Basically I use RadAjaxManager to update controls on a web form, but sometimes certain code is called on the server that should update a control and I need to cause that control to be updated on the screen from code behind. Is there a way to use the RadAjaxManager to achieve this task?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can add RadAjaxManager settings programatically in the code behind -

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(btnSAve, Panel1, null);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, as @user2585781 is not trying to link a button to trigger an update. That is trivial and can be handled as you have demonstrated or hard-coded in the markup. The question being asked is how to trigger the ajax update of a specific control from code-behind. Or are you saying the only possible way to do so is to create a new AjaxSetting and then inject javascript into the page to click the newly-linked button from the client and trigger another post-back that will update the linked control?

Comment: @RlanGillis  - I think my answer is relevant to the question asked. user2585781 is updating data of control  that is being rendered on page during ajax call. In telerik RadAjaxManager, controls that trigger update and controls that gets refreshed needs to be specified in AjaxSettings. It can be done programmatically or in the html markup.